# How to check whether file is signed or not?

Tags: c#, linux, digital-signature, .net-core-3.1

Using X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(FilePath) I have verified whether file is signed or not using c# on windows, but the same code throws exception on Ubuntu-18.04 version.

Code working on Windows 10 using .netcore 3.1 :

```
bool isSigned = true;
X509Certificate certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(file);

                if (certificate != null)
                {
                    string lstrSubject = certificate.Subject;


                    if (lstrSubject.Contains("my Corporation"))
                        isSigned = true;
                    else
                        isSigned = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isSigned = true;
                }
```

I have signed the file with CN = "my corporation" and O ="my corporation".

Exception occurred on Ubuntu-18.04 :

```
error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error
```

I have understood that exception occurred at  X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(file) but I have zero idea about the exception.
Is there any way to check whether file is signed or not using c# code and has to work on cross-platforms (Both windows and linux)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The certificate is XML which is text.  There is a signature block you can see if you open with notepad.  It most likely is signed.  But you have to check the encryption mode that was used create4 certificate.  The encryption mode is not being supported on Ubuntu-18.04. I'm guessing but the certificate may be using a new encryption mode that what is supported in 18 and you may need to install 20.

Comment: Looks like version 20 supports new encryption modes (sha256 and TLS 1.3).  See release history : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: @jdweng I have tried on Ubuntu-20.04, but still seeing the same exception.

Comment: did you do a clean build?  The intermediate object may not of gotten recompiled by just changing the library.  You may need to specify the TLS version. Add ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;  If this fails change to Tls12.